# sqlite SELECT DISTINCT from single column with multiple "names"?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with Chinese Pinyin in it. I want to get all unique syllabic pronunciations.

I ran

```
SELECT DISTINCT col FROM tab
```

but it's giving me too much.

My column has values like

> a1
>
> a2
>
> a3
>
> a4

but it also has multiple word values that might contain a unique value in it like:

> a1 ba1
>
> a2 fa1

How can I use distinct to get values like "ba1" and "fa1" also by themselves?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UNION which also rejects duplicates:

```
select col from tab where col not like '% %'
union
select substr(col, 1, instr(col, ' ') - 1) from tab where col like '% %'
union
select substr(col, instr(col, ' ') + 1) from tab where col like '% %'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4mnDx9UJfbfA1jJ1SytFXw/0)

Comment: Sometimes the values are longer than just two syllables. Is there a way to do it automatically for multiple syllables?

Comment: It can be done, but it gets very complicated for more than 2. Even for 3 it is complicated.

Comment: Yeah, I've got some that are like forty syllables long.